# MATLAB-How can I randomly select smaller values with higher probabilities?

Tags: matlab, random

I have a column vector "distances", and I want to select a value randomly from this vector such that smaller values have a higher probability of being selected. So far I am using the following, where "possible_cells" is the randomly selected value:

```
w=(fliplr(1:numel(distances)))/100
possible_cells=randsample((sort(distances)),1,true,w)
```

Basically, I flipped the distance vector to create probabilities of selection "w" (if I am understanding randsample correctly), so that the smallest value has the probability of being selected equal to the highest value. To check how well this works, I randomly drew 50 values and by using a histogram, I see that the values are higher than I would expect. Does anyone have any idea on how else to do what I described above?
  0 Comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

let's start with 10 sample distances with lengths no greater than 20 just to demonstrate:

```
d = randi(20,10,1);
```

Next, since we want smaller values to be more likely, let's take the reciprocal of those distances:

```
d_rec = 1./d;
```

Now, let's normalize so we can create a distribution from which to select our distance:

```
d_rec_norm = d_rec ./ sum(d_rec);
```

This new variable reflects the probability with which to select each given distance. Now comes a little trick... we choose the distance like this:

```
d_i = find(rand < cumsum(d_rec_norm),1);
```

This will give us the index of our chosen distance. The logic behind this is that when cumulatively summing the normalized values associated with each distance (`d_rec_norm`) we create "bins" whose widths are proportional to the likelihood of selecting each distance. All that is left is to pick a random number between 0 and 1 (`rand`) and see which "bin" it falls in.

I'm a new poster here, so let me know if this is unclear and I can try to improve my explanation.

Comment: Hi @Larry522, after I get d_i, I am a bit confused as to how to proceed and what the purpose of the random number is at the end. "distanced(d_i)" gives me a value corresponding to the chosen index, how does the random number come in?

Comment: The variable `d_i` will be the index of the chosen distance. The actual distance selected would be `d(d_i)`.

Comment: A concrete example with numbers may help to explain how this is working... let's say your distance vector is `d=[5 10]`. Then, `d_rec_norm=[0.6667 0.3333]`, which gives us the probabilities with which we want to select each distance. `cumsum(d_rec_norm)=[0.6667 1.0000]`, which creates the "bins". Then, `rand` produces a random number between 0 and 1. There is a 66% chance that random number is between 0 and 0.6667 and a 33% chance that number is between 0.6667 and 1. The last bit of code for `d_i` will find which "bin" our random number falls in. Does this help?

Comment: I see. In my particular case, "d_rec_norm" has over 1000 very small numbers (.01,.02 etc), and "d_rec_norm" is a vector of zeros. Do you have any idea as to why this may be?

Comment: Turns out the sum of "d_rec" is Inf. Not sure why.

Comment: If you have over 1000 distances, you'd expect at least some of the values of `d_rec_norm` to be very small, since you're slicing up the interval [0,1] into 1000 pieces. Depending on how extreme the difference is between your largest and smallest distance, some probabilities may be sufficiently close to zero that it is below MATLAB's working precision. That would be my best guess, but tough to say for sure without seeing your data.

Comment: If you have distances of 0, the reciprocal of 0 is infinity. That would get you `d_rec=inf`. If this were the case, maybe add a conditional statement that checks for distances of 0 and selects from those first before executing the code I had suggested. A lot of this really depends on your actual objective here, so do what makes sense for you.